# Seletor Universal Não Funciona

Tags: css3

Procurei no fórum e não encontrei perguntar similar a esta, então la vai:

Estou usando o visual studio code como ferramenta para estudo de html, css e js. Atualmente estou trabalhando com CSS, mas percebi que o seletor universal não tem impacto algum do documento que estou criando, onde por exemplo, algo simples como mudar a cor de todo o documento é impossível.

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
color: red
}
```

Esta no topo da stylesheet ...

Demais customizações feitas na página funcionam corretamente, apenas o universal que não ...

Comment: Importou o css na sua página HTML?

Comment: Porque você não usa o html como alvo?

Answer (score 1):

O seletor universal `*` aplica o estilo a todos os elementos da página, `body`, `div`, etc. Porém, como ele está no topo da página, bem provavelmente, esse estilo está sendo sobrescrito pelo estilos que o seguem.

Se você quer colocar o `background` vermelho, aplique-o no `body`, ou até no `html`, certificando-se que não há outra regra sobressaindo por essa. Mas, se você quer, por algum motivo, que todos os elementos fiquem vermelhos, você terá que sobrescrever o que já foi aplicado a esses elementos.

O problema é que colocar o seletor universal no final da página não tem o efeito esperado, já que para o `css`, ele tem um "peso" menor que seletor de *classes*, *ids*, e *tagNames*. Veja:

```css
.exemplo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gold;
  display: inline-block;
}
*{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="exemplo"></div>
<div class="exemplo" ></div>
<div class="exemplo" ></div>
<div class="exemplo" ></div>
```

Repare que mesmo colocando o seletor universal no fim da página, o estilo contido nele não sobrescreve os o que já foi passado.

A ordem de prioridade de seletores no `css` é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entende-a e respeite-a que os estilos terão sucesso.